# Auto scrolls when i refresh the page (HTML, CSS, JS, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Whenever I click my div box that goes to a certain area of the page and refresh it, it always goes back to that same spot.  file:///C:/Users.../index.html#group1 This is url when I click the box and this is before I click the box file:///C:/Users/.../index.html.  How can I fix this?

btw I'm having a similar problem with my checkboxes.  Whenever I scroll down to click the other checkboxes, it always scrolls back to the top. How can I stop that?

EDIT:
Heres what it looks like on my end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORLxv.gif

Code: `enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/mhirai/1gmawr9e/4/

Comment: Can you illustrate the problem?

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code?

Comment: @ItsFragilis  Just posted jsfiddle and recording of my problem

Answer (score 1):

Just check the source code and see where the  tag is pointing at or your div using JavaScript, it's href/path points to '#group1'
That's why your page refreshes and scrolls when you click on the div

There must be a element whose id is "group1"

Answer (score 0):

From the image you provided, it appears that #group1 is trying to point your browser to index.html#group1. If that is not your intended behavior, you can change `<a href="#group1">` to...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.log('test')">
```

You can replace it with your own function call. I'm just using console.log to point out that the href will stop refreshing your page in stead, if you replace the value to javascript:void(0).

You need to provide info on how you formatted your check boxes to behave. It is probably is associated with the **href** tag as in `<a href="3">...</a>` in which case it will behave the same way as your first problem and the solution to that in that case is the same solution I offered to your first problem, if and only if I understand you correctly.

If you intend to scroll to the page element, do it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="scrollToDiv('#group1')">

function scrollToDiv(div){
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(div).offset().top }, 2000);
}
```

The code you provided is very complicated, but try to add this in your javascript. It will mimic the behavior you want:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="pagebottom" class="bottoms" style="border:1px solid black; height:700px; padding:30px;">Bottom div!</div>');
});
function scrollToDiv(div){
    console.log(div);
   setTimeout(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(div).offset().top }, 100);

   },100);
}

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollToDiv("#pagebottom");
    if ($('#122').is(":checked")) {
        $("#123").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#sci").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        
        $('#123').prop('checked', false); $("#123").prop('disabled', true);
        $('#sci').prop('checked', false); $("#sci").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: My intended behavior is to go to that area of the page when the div is clicked, but if I refresh the page, it automatically goes to that area still, not the top of the page. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @MatthewHirai please see if my updated answer is helpful. Otherwise, do a preventDefault() if you don't want to use javascript:void(0) on the href tag.

Comment: @MatthewHirai, you're welcome. :) I'm glad it's helping you after all.